# DataAdapter и MySQL.

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, со следующим. Есть `Datagridview`, подключен к базе. В WinForm автоматом создались необходимые датасеты и адаптеры. Все работает нормально, и сохраняется в базу, и выводится. Далее я написал запрос, который выводит в датагрид только определенные строки, для этого создал новый адаптер и новый датасет (они объявлены глобально, здесь только переопределение):

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM org WHERE t1 = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
adapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в выведенной строке в датагриде изменения тоже сохранялись в базу? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Походу, ответов не было потому, что вопрос на уровне начальной школы? =) Достаточно было добавить коммандбилдер, и все работает (база то из одной таблицы).  Разобрался)